# Dynamically hide column list item if the field is empty

Tags: content-type, caml-query, custom-list, calculated-column, list-form

I have a series of fields that I would like NOT to appear in my list dispForm.aspx. So when a user creates a new list item if these fields are unpopulated the do not appear DispForm.aspx but I still need the EditForm.aspx to show all fields.

I know OOB I am able to hide the list item under content type...this is not what i am looking to achieve.

Is there a way to achieve this with calculated values? ISBLANK (not familiar with the syntax)

Is anyone aware of a solution.

Have tried caml queries such as listed in other posts

```
"<View><Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name="ContentType"/></IsNotNull></Where></Query></View>"
```

As well as

```
"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="ContentType" /><Value Type="Text">Document</Value></Eq><And><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name="ContentType" /></IsNotNull><Neq><FieldRef Name="ContentType" /><Value Type="Text">Document</Value></Neq> </And> </Where></Query></View>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the following js-code into your DispForm.aspx with SharePoint Designer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $.each($('td.ms-formbody'), function() {
      if (!$(this).text().replace(/\xA0/,' ').trim()) {
        $(this).closest('tr').hide();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

You also have to included JQuery-library into DispForm.aspx or master-page.

Comment: Dmitry - thanks heaps for the code snippet - looks just to be just what I need. I will need sum assitance as to where to load the min.js. thanks

Comment: I have added the above script and the script link tag to the DispForm.aspx - I do not see any changes - Do you think it is a misplacement of the script or the link - script link reads as follows: <SharePoint:ScriptLink runat="server" Name="/SiteAssets/js/jquery-1.10.1-min.js" Localizable="false"/>

Comment: Hello, please, try to include jquery-library by using simple html tag: <script language="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/js/jquery-1.10.1-min.js" ></script>

Comment: Thanks Dmitry - still not have any luck with the solution - not hiding any empty fields. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint do you use?

Comment: Using SP 2013. I have tried to use an hosted link to the js library as I did think perhaps my link reference was incorrect - still without luck.

Comment: OK - I have had a moderate amount of success. I have found SPD is not updating my Custom Dispaly Form. I have recreated it and inserted the script with a reference to an external library source (to ensure the script was found). Fields are now not showing but it has done strange things to my output - I have a lookup display in the modal dialog that now appears along with the GUID and hyperlink reference in the text display instead of linked document...my document name which is also a hyperlink does not appear at all. Any suggestions/recommendations gladly received.

Comment: I have placed the script in the <xsl:template name="dvt_1.rowview">

Comment: I can recommend to leave default display form and place js-code before or after ListFormWebPart outside the WebPartZone

Comment: Dmitry - many thanks. I did discover a couple other notable behaviours. I did have hyperlink fields. I do believe the behind code as some sort of preset text in the field which therefore makes it not empty. My lookup field is now intact and my related items also disappears. If you do know a solution for my hyperlink fields this would be most awesome. Thanks kindly for your assistance.

Comment: Just realised my related items disappear as well - working on this one now - any suggestions??? I did think I still had the option but no.

Comment: This code works great but it would be great if it worked if it worked with the boxed style when the list view is grouped

Answer (score 0):

You can write a httpmodule, and do something like this:

```
 private void context_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            Page handler = (Page) HttpContext.Current.Handler;
            string rawUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
            if (rawUrl.Contains("/DispForm.aspx?"))
            {                
                handler.Load += new EventHandler(this.page_Load);//remove those fileds you want to hide in page_Load function.
            }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Raymond - unable to do at this time - do not have a VS project setup (VS installed for that matter). I was hoping to achieve this with caml, jquery or calculated value. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have encountered a problem with my request. The series of fields I do not want to display are not in the DispForm.aspx but in the modal dialog - I was under the impression the DispForm.aspx drove the modal dialog output. I dont think this is correct. Can someone advise please.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do similar with jQuery.  Using SPD you can edit the lists DisplayForm.aspx and add in the script you need to hide the field if it is empty.

Getting the correct field can be a bit of a challenge as it is a dynamically created form - I usually use the attribute "title" which contains the display version of the column name.  The downside to this is that if you change the display name you need to change your script.  Click F12 in IE to get developer mode and you will be able to see the structure of the HTML in the form.

EDIT: Code snippet as requested

```
$("input[title='ExternalColumnName']").parents("tr:first").hide();
```

You will need to check what sort of input/textarea/select etc your fields are and then use the column name to identify them.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a snippet as requested.  This is using jQuery so you will also need the jQuery library active though you could also convert it to javascript if you prefer.